# Is it possible to hide the inheritance of classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

From the outside I would like my class to appear like this

```
@interface MYCardGroupView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *cardObjects;
@end
```

But within the class itself I want it to actually be a UITableView

```
@interface MYCardGroupView : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *cardObjects;
@end
```

Arguments for:

- from an API perspective it makes sense to only reveal the necessary interface
- it feels very excessive to have the UITableView as a subview just to keep the interface unbloated (clean interface vs performance cost of having deeper view tree)

Comment: If you've got a table view internally you don't "unbloat" things by hiding that fact.  Quite the opposite.  If you feel you must hide it, use a protocol.

Comment: @HotLicks well from an API perspective I must say it bloats or give away excessive information about the underlying processes. Also gives access to break the wanted behavior (e.g. sets delegate when delegate should be self in this case).

Comment: That's not "bloat".  And if you want a secure language, don't use Objective-C.

Comment: When writing an API or a bundle of classes it is important to tell the developers what's designed to be possible and not. I'm not concerned about security. Devs can swizzle this and pose-as and do all kinds of magic, but that's on them.

Comment: That's what comments and documentation are for.

Comment: Okay, I take it you don't value a tidy and clean interface where it is clear to all devs how to interact with that class/component. I also take it you deem comments to always be in sync with actual code, always. And that code can rather be commented than written in a unambigous way. Nothing beats unambigous, self-documenting code.

Comment: Except that "self-documenting" code hardly ever is.

Comment: Well, I will certainly at least strive for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the protocols it implements (like `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`) by adding them to a class extension in your .m file. But you can't hide that it's a UITableView subclass.

However, it shouldn't hurt performance to have an extra UIView, at least not in any noticeable way. There are extra views that you don't notice all over the place in the built-in UIKit elements, and the impact is likely very minimal. If you're that worried about performance, leave it as a UITableView subclass. But if you're not so worried and you care more about concealing as much as possible, make it a UIView subclass and have it encapsulate a UITableView instead.

Comment: Neat trick to add the protocols in category-interface! The protocols were just the minor part here, but interesting anyway!

Answer (score 4):

One could, in theory, employ two separate .h files, one "real" one, only named "MyClass_real.h" and one fake one, named "MyClass.h".  Include the real one in your .m but use the fake one as the advertised interface.  The fake one could say your base class is "Potato" and it wouldn't make any difference.

(One would have to be a bit concerned about ARC, I suppose.  It might get upset.)

Comment: @hfossli - Nope, that's not what I'm talking about.  There should only be one class named.  (The .h name does not have to correspond to the class name.)

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the protocols outside of the header (via a class extension — an unnamed category) but not technically the inheritance. That's because usually you want the inheritance to be known.

Immediately obvious workarounds include:

- declare the public class which is a sub of `UIView`, have its `init` or `alloc` substitute an instance of another class that otherwise follows the same published interface but is a sub of `UITableViewController`; and
- use the deprecated [`class_setSuperclass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_setSuperclass) (deprecated since day one but still available) to change your superclass at `init`.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea to attempt. Hacks like this should only be used if there is no other possible solution, but there is in this case.

Comment: The second idea is probably a bad idea, but I'd argue the first is fine. It's explicitly acceptable behaviour, being how class clusters are implemented. The Objective-C conventions are established explicitly to allow `[[ClassA alloc] init]` to return an instance of `ClassB`. So I wouldn't characterise doing so as a hack.

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is effectively a *class cluster*, with a cluster size of 1 - unusual maybe but quite legitimate.

A number of classes in the standard frameworks; e.g. `NSString`; are implemented as *clusters* where the public class is "abstract" (not in the traditional OO sense) and one or more private classes provide the actual implementation(s). On creating an instance of the public class its `init` (or `alloc`) substitutes and instance of one of the private classes.

This is a well defined model in Cocoa, see Apple's [Cocoa Core Competencies: Class Cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ClassCluster.html)

Comment: @hfossli - Look through the Apple docs and elsewhere, for example there is example code on [this Apple page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH4). In your case you might wish to bend the first rule as defined on that page - your private concrete subclass is actually a subclass of your public abstract classes *superclass* rather than the abstract class itself. If you are going to be doing `isMemberOf:` tests you'll need to override that method to maintain your illusion. HTH

Answer (score 0):

This works from a functional perspective, but has following drawbacks

- throws error in `+[MYCardGroupView alloc]`: `Incompatible pointer types returning 'MYPrivateCardGroupView *' from a function with result type 'MYCardGroupView *'`
- the extra work of having to declare everything twice

#### .h-file

```
@interface MYCardGroupView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *cardObjects;
@end
```

#### .m-file

```
#import "MYCardGroupView.h"

@interface MYPrivateCardGroupView : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *cardObjects;
@end

@implementation MYCardGroupView

+ (id)alloc
{
    return [MYPrivateCardGroupView alloc];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        NSLog(@"My class is %@", [self class]);
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation MYPrivateCardGroupView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        NSLog(@"My class is %@", [self class]);
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"hello";
    return cell;
}

@end
```

#### Logs

```
My class is MYPrivateCardGroupView
```